# Better way to write CSS classes with common child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say this is my HTML:

```
<div class="example">
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="blah">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

I want to style every `span` except for the `span` in `.foo`. I can't use `:not` because I have way too many `div`s (parent elements) that I want to ignore in my actual code, more so than the parent elements I'm trying to target. So this is what I'm currently doing:

```
.example span, .test span, .blah span {
```

This is kind of decent if it's just one rule, but it's not; my code ends up looking like this:

```
.example span, .test span, .blah span {
}

.example span:hover, .test span:hover, .blah span:hover {
}

.example span:before, .test span:before, .blah span:before,
.example span:after, .test span:after, .blah span:after {
}
```

This gets tedious quickly. What is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Class the spans. Or class the span in `.foo`, and then `span:not(.foo-span)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS is tedious. Use SASS or LESS to compile your CSS and save yourself some headaches.

In SCSS (SASS):

```
.example,
.test,
.blah {
  span {
    &:hover {

    }
    &:before,
    &:after {

    }
  }
}
```

Learn more at:
http://sass-lang.com and http://compass-style.org

Answer (score 1):

you could add extra classes to your divs and chain them in your declarations; so pretend you want add .bold class on the span in div.blah, you would do this:
`.blah.bold span{}`  that could also easily get bloated if not checked, but in your situation sounds like a nice fit.